# How can i send an array from one action to another in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How can i send an indexed array or assertive array from one action to another in zend.. Both the 2 functions are in same controller..

Comment: did you try serialize and unserialize ? Use that two functions and pass the array with $_GET or $_POST

Comment: How are you calling the 2nd action ? Are you doing a `_redirect()`, a `_forward()` or simply calling it like you would call any method inside a same object ? If you're doing (or can do) the 3rd one, just pass it as a regular parameter.

Answer (score 6):

inside action one

```
Zend_Registry::set("myArray",$myArray);
```

inside action two

```
$myArray =  Zend_Registry::get("myArray");
```

This will work if you are using "forward" action helper to jump from one action to another if you are doing it through redirection then you got to store it in session or use flashMessenger action helper

Comment: Hi but when i tried this it showed me the following error include_once(Zend\Registery.php) and Class 'Zend_Registery' not found in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: I made a spelling mistake of Registery instead of Registry now check

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can set a param of the request object, and it is then accessible from the next acton. Preventing polluting the global registry.

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('key', $value);
```